# Is it possible in mongodb push cloning existing array elements to be part of new array object?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So far, I've managed to prepend a new element to the profile array. My goal is to add a new department and clone existing details from recent profile e.g job title. I can't figure out how to clone it, I tried `job: "$profile.job", job: $profile.job` or if it is even possible?

```
db.getCollection('employees').update(
  { "profile.depId": ObjectId('5aaa53f6207dc50c53ae4967'), "companyId": ObjectId('5aa6069648ac9b1668dfc2a0') },
  { "$push": { "profile":  { $each: [{ depName: "Test", job: "$profile.job" }], $position: 0  } } },
  { "multi": true }
)
```

Or do I have to do two queries to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think MongoDB will allow you to use an existing field to create a new one. Instead, try getting the cursor and update each doc using `forEach`:

```
db.employees.find({  
   "profile.depId":ObjectId('5aaa53f6207dc50c53ae4967'),
   "companyId":ObjectId('5aa6069648ac9b1668dfc2a0')
}).snapshot().forEach( 
    function (empDoc){  
   db.employees.update(   {  
      _id:empDoc._id
   },
   {  
      "$push":{  
         "profile":{  
            $each:[  
               {  
                  depName:"Test",
                  job:empDoc.profile.jo"
               }
            ],
            $position:0
         }
      }
   }   );
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this as guide but didn't use the snapshot as for some reason I can't get it to work. :)